# Failed to build quarkus application:

Tags: quarkus

I upgraded Quarkus from 2.6.1.Final  to 2.7.1.Final

And my build now gives :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.7.1.Final:build (default) on project testapp: Failed to build quarkus application: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[ERROR]         [error]: Build step 
io.quarkus.smallrye.openapi.deployment.SmallRyeOpenApiProcessor#build threw an exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.ContentReference com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory._createContentReference(java.lang.Object)'
[ERROR]         at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory.createGenerator(YAMLFactory.java:441)
[ERROR]         at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory.createGenerator(YAMLFactory.java:15)
[ERROR]         at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.createGenerator(ObjectWriter.java:703)
[ERROR]         at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValueAsString(ObjectWriter.java:1085)
[ERROR]         at io.smallrye.openapi.runtime.io.OpenApiSerializer.serialize(OpenApiSerializer.java:48)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.smallrye.openapi.deployment.SmallRyeOpenApiProcessor.build(SmallRyeOpenApiProcessor.java:630)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:882)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
```

Comment: Please see answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70422060/object-mapper-yamlfactory-exception-due-to-missing-createcontentreference-m/70422163#70422163

You have different versions of the same dependency on your build path.